# Problem with plotting data using datetime format for xticks

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, formatting, xticks

I have a time series that I obtain from a numerical simulation with an integration time step of 1min. This time series spans several months and I want to use dates in the x-axis.
Once the integration is over I add an epoch time corresponding with the first day to the time numpy array created as

```
tt = np.arange(0.0, number_of_days, minute)
```

I only pick up data points every 10 mins (`tt[::10]`).
I convert this array to the date format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` via

```
dtime = np.empty(len(tt[::10]), dtype="S19")
for ind, t in enumerate(tt[::10]):
   daytime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t))
   dtime[ind] = datetime.strptime(daytime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

`print(dtime)` results in:

```
[b'2020-01-22 00:00:00' b'2020-01-22 00:10:00' b'2020-01-22 00:20:00' ...
 b'2020-06-29 23:30:00' b'2020-06-29 23:40:00' b'2020-06-29 23:50:00']
```

I format the xticks as:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
```

I plot this data with:

```
plt.plot_date(dtime, Y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

I get the same result if I only use `plt.plot`.
I get no xticks with the dates unfortunately.
It seems dates are not properly formatted in datetime format so that matplotlib understands it. I suspect the problem has to do with dtime, which I think should not be of string type.
The result is

[image]

I would like to plot this time series with this graph, which has one data point per day.

[image]

I have a second related question here: how to set the major ticks at biweekly intervals?

When I plot both datasets together I get this:

[image]

**Update:** Based on the solution proposed by Andrea, I can now plot both datasets in the same graph as below

[image]

Comment: use `plt.scatter`?

Comment: The problem is with formatting the xtics. Using scatter won't help it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you use `pd.date_range` to generate the dtime array?

```
dtime = pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-22', end = '2020-06-29', freq = '10min')
```

In this way, the `dtime` is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-22 00:00:00', '2020-01-22 00:10:00',
               '2020-01-22 00:20:00', '2020-01-22 00:30:00',
               '2020-01-22 00:40:00', '2020-01-22 00:50:00',
               '2020-01-22 01:00:00', '2020-01-22 01:10:00',
               '2020-01-22 01:20:00', '2020-01-22 01:30:00',
               ...
               '2020-06-28 22:30:00', '2020-06-28 22:40:00',
               '2020-06-28 22:50:00', '2020-06-28 23:00:00',
               '2020-06-28 23:10:00', '2020-06-28 23:20:00',
               '2020-06-28 23:30:00', '2020-06-28 23:40:00',
               '2020-06-28 23:50:00', '2020-06-29 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=22897, freq='10T')
```

---

With this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dtime = pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-22', end = '2020-06-29', freq = '10min')
X = np.linspace(-10, 10, len(dtime))
Y = np.exp(X) / (np.exp(X) + 1)

plt.plot(dtime, Y)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval = 7))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval = 1))
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 45 )
plt.gca().set_xlim(dtime[0], dtime[-1])

plt.show()
```

I get this plot:

[image]

Since I do not have access to your `Y` data, I generated a sigmoid function in order to make the plot; replace it with your data.